# How to remove duplicates in a string column from a hive table

Tags: hive, duplicates

I have column(string) space separated with duplicate values. I want to remove duplicates:
e.g.

```
column_name
-----------------
gun gun man gun man
shuttle enemy enemy run
hit chase
```

I want result like:

```
column_name
----------------
gun man
shuttle enemy run
hit chase
```

I am using hive database.Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicates in hive string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874823/how-to-remove-duplicates-in-hive-string)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

without custom UDFs, this is one way to do with only query.

```
select id, concat_ws(' ',collect_set(splited)) as column_name
from
(
  select id, splited
  from tbl_name
  LATERAL VIEW explode(split(column_name,' ')) t as splited
  group by id, splited
) x
group by id
```

Comment: This is sorting the set of words, any way we can do this conserving the original order ?